# Encoding transparent animated gif in Java

Tags: java, image, transparency, gif, animated-gif

I am using `GifDecoder` to read an animated .gif file and `AnimGifEncoder` to write it.  ([link](http://www.fmsware.com/stuff/gif.html))

If I display the original frames read by `GifDecoder` they display correctly and are transparent, but if I display the frames created by `AnimatedGifEncoder` the transparency is all wrong.

```
   GifDecoder gif = new GifDecoder();
   gif.read("image.gif");

   AnimatedGifEncoder e = new AnimatedGifEncoder();
   e.start("newimage.gif");
   e.setTransparent(Color.BLACK);

   for (int i=0;i<gif.getFrameCount();i++) {
        anim.addFrame(gif.getFrame(i));
        anim.setDelay(gif.getDelay(i));
   }

   anim.finish();
```

In this example I set the transparent color to black.  But actually I want to get the transparent color information from the `GifDecoder` but I don't know how.

Comment: Does [GIFanim](http://pscode.org/gifanim/) encode the image as you expect?  If so, I might be tempted into hauling out the code & summarizing it for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following solution, although there are still some gif files that
are a mess after scaling... :

(At least it seems to get along with most non-transparent gifs)

```
Color transparentColor = null;
BufferedImage firstFrameImage = ImageIO.read([sourceFileHere]);

if (firstFrameImage.getColorModel() instanceof IndexColorModel) {
   IndexColorModel cm = (IndexColorModel) firstFrameImage.getColorModel();
   int transparentPixel = cm.getTransparentPixel();
   transparentColor = new Color(cm.getRGB(transparentPixel), true);
}

e.setTransparent(transparentColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was all a long time ago, but I did manage to get it working at the time.  Without digging out the code again... I got it working by:

1. Scan the original image and set the transparent areas to a colour that does not exist inside the original image.
2. Set the transparent colour inside the AnimGifEncoder to the colour that was previously assigned to the transparent areas.